# surfaces of spheres are made of

Tags: geometry, surfaces

Sorry in advance for lacking the appropriate terminology, please help me edit it in below.

Take thease basic shapes:

```
triangle, square, ..., octigon
pyramid, cube
simplex, hypercube
```

Each flat surface of a cube is a square. The same applies to others in the rest of the table above.

{circle, sphere, hypersphere} also have a great deal in common with thease series.

**Therefore, is it true to say that a surface of a sphere either is, or is in some respects, or can be thought of as being a circle, or more accurately a disc**?

My thoughts as to how this could be:

A segment or slice isn't a surface.

Thanks Qiaochu Yuan, in topologically two discs can be used to form a sphere. Although they are not flat discs.

Perhaps as the number of sides approaches infinity, the shape of each side aproaches a circle, although it's apparent that circular surfaces do not fit together to form a sphere.

Comment: So the question is?..

Comment: I've marked the question.

Comment: Everything below the bolded question is my thoughts of how this could be.

Comment: Well, you would be certainly interested in [Algebraic topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_topology) which in part deals with such 'common things'. I don't know if there is a good introductory book on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly it is possible to think of a sphere as being glued together from several disks (in mathematics "circle" refers to the object $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ rather than the object $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$, which is a disk). In fact it suffices to use two: the upper hemisphere and the lower hemisphere of a sphere are [topologically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology) disks, and gluing them together at their boundaries gives a sphere.

The study of topological spaces from this point of view used to be known as [combinatorial topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_topology), but nowadays it is subsumed under [algebraic topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_topology).

Comment: This is probably as good an answer as there is, but I suspect OP is thinking of geometry, not topology. In geometry, things go wrong way before you get to spheres; there's already nothing in the second row of the table to correspond to hexagons and heptagons in the first row.

Comment: The disks would have to be distorted or stretched for that to work, try doing this with rubber without streching the rubber or creating a cut to reduce the length of the perimeter. Perhaps this stretching is expected in topologically. I'm more interested in the way it can seemingly be proven that a sphere can be constructed of flat disks when it's also apparently not true.

Comment: @alan2here: yes, some distortion is inevitable. As a geometric object, the sphere (with the usual metric) has nonzero Gaussian curvature (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature) everywhere, while disks (with the usual metric) have zero Gaussian curvature everywhere.

Comment: So as I suspected, appart from my proof above proving it's possible it's definitely impossible :¬P